# How to get parameter values of rich:hashParam

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to pass values to rich:popupPanel with rich:hashParam tag, here is my code

```
<h:commandLink value="Edit">
<rich:componentControl target="editPanel" operation="show">
    <a4j:param noEscape="true" value="event" />
    <rich:hashParam>
        <a4j:param name="categoryId" value="#{ c.categoryId }" />
        <a4j:param name="categoryName" value="#{ c.name }" />
        <a4j:param name="categoryParent" value="#{ c.parent }" />
    </rich:hashParam>
</rich:componentControl>
```

And here is my popup panel which user can do something

```
<rich:popupPanel id="editPanel" autosized="true">
    <!-- how to get value of the rich:hashParam? -->
</rich:popupPanel>
```

I have referred the richfaces document and examples about rich:hashParam to find out how to get values within the rich:popupPanel. But it seems that the document contains few about rich:hashParam and the example is hard coded, not passed by rich:hashParam.

Document : [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Functionality_extension.html#sect-Component_Reference-Functionality_extension-richhashParam)

Example : [Here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=hashParam&skin=blueSky)

Does anyone have idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have solved this problem myself. Instead of passing parameters with `rich:hashParam`, I passed parameters to the popup panel with `a4j:param` and assign the value to a backing bean property. Then re-render an `a4j:outputPanel` which displays the parameter values.

```
<h:form id="editDataForm">
    <!-- server do something with the 'categoryId' parameter it gets -->
    <a4j:commandLink action="#{ testBackingBean.editData }" value="Edit" render="dataContent" oncomplete="#{rich:component('editPanel')}.show()">
        <a4j:param name="data" value="#{ c.categoryId }" assignTo="#{ testBackingBean.categoryId }"/>
    </a4j:commandLink>
</h:form>
<!--...-->
<rich:popupPanel id="editPanel">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="dataContent" layout="inline">
        <h:outputText value="ID:"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{ testBackingBean.dataToEdit.categoryId }"/>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</rich:popupPanel>
```